# Destructive sorting of React useState hook variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

One of the props into this component is an array of values, and I'd like to sort those values. I've done so with the following:

```js
const MyComponent = items => {
    const [sortedItems, setSortedItems] = useState(items)

    useEffect(() => sortedItems.sort(), [sortedItems])

    /* rest of component code */
}
```

It definitely *seems* like it doesn't fit with the spirit of React and Hooks, but it works. I'm not looking for alternate implementation approaches, but what I'm super curious about is: is the approach here counter-indicated by the React documentation?

Comment: It goes against how React's reconciliation algorithm works. `sort` is a mutative process and `sortedItem` changes won't (or at least shouldn't) trigger a rerender in its own rite. Oftentimes, mutative changes in state (a very bad thing) will seem like it's working because a parent triggered a rerender and the change propagated down to the component in question. It is rerendering by coincidence, as opposed to a direct consequence of its own action

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is the approach here counter-indicated by the React documentation?

Yes. Normally, updating the state should call its setState function, but we see here that using `sort` mutates `sortedItems` without calling `setSortedItems`. The approach to use `setSortedItems` instead can be implemented like so:

```
useEffect(() => setSortedItems([...sortedItems].sort()), [sortedItems])
```

(I know you said not looking for alternative approaches, but please take this as an example so I can explain.)

The important point is that this will not mutate the previous `sortedItems` before triggering a render. This is so that the next DOM render and anywhere that reads `sortedItems` will be consistent.

---

#### Update

Although the render and accesses to `sortedItems` will be consistent, it may not contain the value that's expected in subsequent updates because of how React's state updates are queued asynchronously (this issue is also prevalent in OP's example). The issue arises when the time to sort subsequent `sortedItems` vary greatly, but there can be other causes as well.

React docs explains this behavior in their docs for `setState`:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

> Subsequent calls will override values from previous calls in the same cycle, so the quantity will only be incremented once. If the next state depends on the current state, we recommend using the updater function form, instead:
>
> ```
> this.setState((state) => {
>    return {quantity: state.quantity + 1};
> });
> ```

In our example, it's a minor change of adding a callback to the example:

```
useEffect(() => setSortedItems((prevSortedItems) => [...prevSortedItems].sort()), [sortedItems])
```

Comment: I would recommend to change `setSortedItems([...sortedItems].sort())` to something like this: `setSortedItems(previousItems => [...previousItems].sort())`. Since `setSortedItems` will be worked on asynchronously, it _can_ happen, that `sortedItems` have been modified between access and set actually setting.

Comment: Updated answer :)